# Micro services booking and payment approach

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices

I am doing a POC on Hotel booking platform, and i am using micro services approach (Backed Spring Boot with MySQL and front end in Angular), with a simple use case like

- Check hotel availability
- Book hotel
- Payment

Divided the code it following micro services

- Booking Service
- Payment Service
- Hotel Inventory Service

Lets suppose we have UI Page where we clicked **Book Now** Button, following sequence of events will occur

1. Booking Service API is fired and order is created in **PENDING** State, and also an event is created like **"Order created Event"**
2. Hotel Inventory Service reads the **"Order created Event"** and further creates **"Success Event"** (Assuming Inventory is available)
3. Booking Service reads the **"Success Event"** and change the status to NEW State and booking is successful.

So my question is how to redirect user to external payment gateway, as the above approach is event based ?

Is there any better approach we can implement with this use case ?

Comment: [Code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) might prove a better forum for this.

Comment: I just want to know the approach, how this use case can be done with micro services.